# Initialization vector is not supported in gwt

Tags: java, encryption, gwt

I am trying to decrypt using initialization vector and key at client side, but the GWT is not able to recognize it, I added crypto library but still it is not supported. How can I use initialization vector to make encryption and decryption more secure.

At server side i am able to encrypt but at client side i am not able to decrypt..
KeyGenerator and IvParameterSpec is not supported by GWT

```
private String encryptDES(String sessionKey) throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESede");
    SecretKey myKey = keygenerator.generateKey();
    SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom(); 
    byte [] iv = new byte[8]; 
    sr.nextBytes(iv); 
    IvParameterSpec IV = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myKey, IV);
    String encrypted = Base64.encode(cipher.doFinal(sessionKey.getBytes()));
    return encrypted;
}
```

please help me resolving it

Answer (score 3):

Write a wrapper around cryptoJS
Should be less than 100 lines of code.

Inject for example aes from crypto.js

```
String url = GWT.getModuleBaseForStaticFiles() + "js/aes.js";
ScriptInjector.fromUrl(url).setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW).inject();
```

Encrypt

```
/**
 * Encrypt the given String with the given key.
 *
 * @param s The String to encrypt
 * @param cipher The cipher
 * @return The encrypted String
 */
 public static native String encrypt(String s, String cipher)
 /*-{
    var key = $wnd.CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(cipher);
    var iv = $wnd.CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(cipher);

    var encrypted = $wnd.CryptoJS.AES.encrypt($wnd.CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(s), key,
    {
       keySize: 128 / 8,
       iv: iv,
       mode: $wnd.CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
       padding: $wnd.CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

    return encrypted;
 }-*/;
```

Decrypt

```
/**
 * Decrypt the given String with the given key.
 *
 * @param s The String to decrypt
 * @param cipher The key
 * @return The decrypted String
 */
public static native String decrypt(String s, String cipher)
/*-{
   var key = $wnd.CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(cipher);
   var iv = $wnd.CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(cipher);

   var decrypted = $wnd.CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(s, key,
   {
      keySize: 128 / 8,
      iv: iv,
      mode: $wnd.CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
      padding: $wnd.CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
   });

   return decrypted.toString($wnd.CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}-*/;
```

Comment: I tried using JSNI but didnt worked.. I already have the TripleDes implementation but with hardcoded key value.. now i want the key to be more secured so it must be randomly generated.. I tired some approch but none was working.. I wasn't able to find any solution on Internet for generating key randomly that is GWT supported.. Please provide any Example